# How to call Terminal Commands in a TEXT File?

Tags: node.js

I really need help on this, couldn't find much examples on google.

For example:
I have this web project. Inside this project there is, app.js, views/home.ejs, some npm packages and etc...

This project, we are not allowed to type "npm install" "npm start" to run our project or we get a zero. The teacher will only type 1 line in terminal which is "run app.py" for python or "run js app" to run our code, will not install packages on localhost.

Wants us to make a textfile to automatically install all packages in the background and run the application automatically? How would I do that?

For example in text file:

inside TXT.FILE {
#1 run "npm install express" in terminal

#2 run "npm install body-parser" in terminal

#3 run "node app.js" in terminal

#4 also run "ls"
}

Basically just call terminal commands in a text file. A text file that will automatically execute them in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Add this into your `package.json` file

```
...
 "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "npm install express && npm install body-parser && node app.js && ls"
  },
```

Now you can use `npm start` to run all these commands at one go.

2. Add a bash script in your project directory.
   The file should be named `your-script-name.sh`.
   Inside add

```
#!/bin/bash
npm install express && npm install body-parser && node app.js && ls
```

You can run the script using `./your-script-name.sh` in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

"scripts": {
...
"start": "npm install express && npm install body-parser && node app.js && ls"
},

Yes this works very well, tested it! Thank you.

This calls terminal commands under 1 line of code!